# How to use reactive() inside of a reactiveValues()?

Tags: r, shiny

The following is just a reprex but i am making an app where the following situation occurs. A reactive() is used inside of reactiveValues(). When i do this i get an error.
Check out the line where you see :

**dd<-reactive(d1)**

**DF1 <- reactiveValues(data=dd())**

```
Admit<-c("Admitted","Rejected","Admitted", "Rejected", "Admitted", "Rejected", "Admitted",
         "Rejected","Admitted", "Rejected", "Admitted","Rejected","Admitted", "Rejected","Admitted","Rejected", "Admitted", "Rejected",
         "Admitted","Rejected", "Admitted" ,"Rejected","Admitted", "Rejected")
Gender<-c("Male","Male","Female","Female", "Male",   "Male",   "Female", "Female", "Male","Male","Female","Female",
          "Male","Male","Female","Female","Male",   "Male",   "Female", "Female","Male","Male","Female","Female")
Dept<-c( "A","A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "E", "E", "F", "F", "F", "F")
Freq<-c("512", "313",  "89",  "19", "353", "207",  "17",   "8", "120", "205", "202", "391", "138", "279", "131", "244",  "53", "138",
        "94", "299",  "22", "351",  "24", "317")

banking.df<-data.frame(Admit,Gender,Dept, Freq,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
d1 = banking.df
d1$Date = Sys.time() + seq_len(nrow(d1))

library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("UC Berkley Admissions"),
  
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      id = 'dataset',
      tabPanel("Sample Bank",
               
               DT::DTOutput("banking.df_data"),
               tableOutput('table'),
               
               br(),
               actionButton("saveBtn","Save"),
               br(),
               actionButton(inputId = "reset", label = "Reset")
               
      ))))

server <- function(input, output) {
  dd<-reactive(d1)
  DF1 <- reactiveValues(data=dd())

  output$banking.df_data<-renderDT(
    DF1$data, editable = TRUE
    
   
  )
  
  observeEvent(input$banking.df_data_cell_edit, {
    req(input$banking.df_data_cell_edit)
    d1[input$banking.df_data_cell_edit$row,input$banking.df_data_cell_edit$col] <<- input$banking.df_data_cell_edit$value
    DF1$data <- d1
  })
  output$table <- renderTable(DF1$data)
  
  
  

  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: OK, but why you can't just use `DF1 <- reactiveValues(data=d1)`? And remove this: `dd<-reactive(d1)`?

Comment: In my actual shiny app , a dataframe comes from a reactive() function which is then used in multiple places. In the reactive() function i get the data from rhandsontable package

Comment: Nesting reactives is a fundamental error.  Reactives are functions, just like any other.  R's scoping rules mean that a reactive defined inside another is not available to Shiny's "alert system" that controls reactivity.  See [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/understanding-reactivity.html) for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reactive objects could be assigned in an observer. Try this

```
Admit<-c("Admitted","Rejected","Admitted", "Rejected", "Admitted", "Rejected", "Admitted",
         "Rejected","Admitted", "Rejected", "Admitted","Rejected","Admitted", "Rejected","Admitted","Rejected", "Admitted", "Rejected",
         "Admitted","Rejected", "Admitted" ,"Rejected","Admitted", "Rejected")
Gender<-c("Male","Male","Female","Female", "Male",   "Male",   "Female", "Female", "Male","Male","Female","Female",
          "Male","Male","Female","Female","Male",   "Male",   "Female", "Female","Male","Male","Female","Female")
Dept<-c( "A","A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "E", "E", "F", "F", "F", "F")
Freq<-c("512", "313",  "89",  "19", "353", "207",  "17",   "8", "120", "205", "202", "391", "138", "279", "131", "244",  "53", "138",
        "94", "299",  "22", "351",  "24", "317")

d1 <- data.frame(Admit,Gender,Dept, Freq,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
d1$Date = Sys.time() + seq_len(nrow(d1))

library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("UC Berkley Admissions"),
  
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      id = 'dataset',
      tabPanel("Sample Bank",
               
               DT::DTOutput("banking.df_data"),
               tableOutput('table'),
               br(),
               actionButton("saveBtn","Save"),
               br(),
               actionButton(inputId = "reset", label = "Reset")
               
      ))))

server <- function(input, output) {
  dd<-reactive(d1)
  DF1 <- reactiveValues(data=NULL)
  observe({ DF1$data <- dd() })
  
  output$banking.df_data<-renderDT(
    DF1$data, editable = TRUE)
  
  observeEvent(input$banking.df_data_cell_edit, {
    DF1$data[input$banking.df_data_cell_edit$row,input$banking.df_data_cell_edit$col] <<- input$banking.df_data_cell_edit$value
  })
  
  output$table <- renderTable(DF1$data)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```